# My iPad Mini isn't responding to the magnets in the cover; any fix?

Tags: ipad, smart-cover

Recently, my iPad Mini has stopped responding to the sleep/wake magnets in my cover. Is there any fix for this other than taking it in for a hardware fix?

Comment: It's not a magnet, it's just a light sensor detecting if the cover is on or off.

Comment: @IronCraftMan It's a magnet. If you've ever replaced the digitizer on an iPad, you'll have to put the magnets from the old digitizer onto the new one. Also, the iPad won't lock the screen just because it detects something on top of it, you can test that yourself, just put a magazine or something on top of your iPad and it won't lock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Settings > General and if "Lock / Unlock" is off, turn it on. If it's on, turn it off, then back on and then restart your iPad by holding the home button and lock button together until you see an Apple logo appear. Don't worry, it won't effect any content on your iPad, but it might be necessary to fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks. It turns out that someone turned Lock/Unlock off.